# Perl can't catch bzip2 console output

Tags: perl, bzip2

I have some difficulties with my perl + gtk GUI app. Why can't perl catch bzip2's output text from console? Instead of being catched into variable, output is just printed in console. I have no problem with any other program - it's just bzip2.

My code:

```
wypisz($cmd);
my $out = `$cmd`;
wypisz($out);
wypisz("end");
```

Result: `$cmd` and "end" printed properly - nothing more. Bzip2's output is just printed`wypisz()` is my function used to put the text into `gtkTextView`:

```
sub wypisz {
    my $text = shift;
    my $textbuffer = $::Glade->get_widget( 'v_console' )->get_buffer;
    my $textiter = $textbuffer->get_end_iter;
    $textbuffer->insert($textiter,"$text\n");
    $::Glade->get_widget( 'v_console' )->set_buffer($textbuffer)
}
```

Comment: check if bzip's writing to stderr. if it is, then you'd have to `$cmd 2>1` to redirect stderr to stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
my $out = `$cmd 2>&1`;
```

to redirect stderr to stdout

Comment: This is it, thank you! :) @MarcB proposed similar thing in one of the comments, but without the ampersand, so it didn't work.

Comment: @RafałSwacha Without the ampersand, you will redirect your output to a file named `1`.